# Laravel Yajra datatables ajax serverside slow down page load

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I'm using Yajra datatables with serverside true, but page load very slow (afraid because of distinct count). I tried solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69294654/3613026) by removing ->get() and it load faster but this causing another problem, where the input searching (smart: true) return error, not functioning. Anyone can help?

Here is my code:

```
$links = Link::with('owner')
->withCount(['clicks as uniqueClicks' => function($q) {
      $q->select(DB::raw('count(distinct(ip_address))'));
}])
->where('account_id', $account_id)
->orderBy('created_at','desc')
->get(); 

return Datatables::of($links)->make();
```

Is it possible to optimize this code? maybe change from select raw distinct to groupBy? or do this more on eloquent way?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @sta error on any search query: DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Exception Message:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake for not stating the full errors and in the error mentioned about laravel relationship column not found.

Here is the documentation https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/relationships

```
columns: [
    // columns according to JSON
    { data: '' },
    { data: 'title' },
    { data: 'user_name', name: 'user.manage.name' }, <-- name = relationship column
    { data: 'link' },
    { data: 'created_at', "searchable": false },
    { data: 'action' }
  ],
```

So removing the ->get() do make your page load faster.

```
$links = Link::with('owner')
->withCount(['clicks as uniqueClicks' => function($q) {
  $q->select(DB::raw('count(distinct(ip_address))'));
}])
->where('account_id', $account_id)
->orderBy('created_at','desc');

return Datatables::of($links)->make();
```